# Display loading while Caching image from URL

Tags: c#, wpf, image, loading, mahapps.metro

I have a code in WPF C# that i use to load images from the web as such:

```
if (myImgURL != "")
{
    var imgBitmap = new BitmapImage();
    imgBitmap.BeginInit();
    imgBitmap.UriSource = new Uri(myImgURL, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    imgBitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    imgBitmap.EndInit();
    myImgControl.Source = imgBitmap;
}
```

It works perfectly but sometimes it takes a while before the images get displayed (if internet is slow and all). How can I have a ProgressRing (from the [Mahapps.Metro](http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/) toolkit) display and be enabled while the image loads and then disappear when the image is displayed?

I am not aware of any event trigger for when an image is being downloaded and when it is fully loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the following events in class BitmapSource (the base class of BitmapImage):

- [DownloadProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.downloadprogress.aspx)
- [DownloadCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.downloadcompleted.aspx)
- [DownloadFailed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.downloadfailed.aspx)

---

And just a note. You are creating a BitmapImage from an Uri and showing it immediately. Hence there is no need to set `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad` (which afaik is necessary only if you load from a stream that should be closed immediately after `EndInit`). So you could shorten your code like this:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myImgURL))
{
    var imgBitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri(myImgURL));
    myImgControl.Source = imgBitmap;

    if (imgBitmap.IsDownloading)
    {
        // start download animation here

        imgBitmap.DownloadCompleted += (o, e) =>
        {
            // stop download animation here
        };

        imgBitmap.DownloadFailed += (o, e) =>
        {
            // stop download animation here
        };
    }
```